# Getting error while adding twilio chat library

Tags: android, twilio

adding library in gradle is

```
compile 'com.twilio:chat-android:0.12.1'
```

and sync then getting error as

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

<Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

versions i am targetting

```
` defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.app.ommo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

in manifest file i am not changing any code and only when i put above library into gradle i am getting that error. my manifest file is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.app.ommo">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ommo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Red">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".jockey.audio.RecorderActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <!--<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>-->
    </activity>



    <activity android:name=".activity.SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <data
                android:host="www.rajasekher.com"
                android:scheme="http" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="t4jsample"
                android:scheme="oauth" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="litestcalback"
                android:scheme="x-oauthflow-linkedin" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".service.MyService" />
    <service android:name=".service.UpdateUserLatLang_Service" />
    <service android:name=".service.Attended_Service" />
    <service android:name=".service.DownloadService" />

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/APP_ID" />

    <!--
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_map_api_key" />
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_place_api" />

    <activity
        android:name=".thirdpartylib.TwitWebViewActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ForgetPasswordActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.RegistrationActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SettingPage"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.TermsandConditions"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.PrivacyPolicy"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.UserAddressListPage"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.AddressPostActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.UserReviewsandRating"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.AppLanguageSetting"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.BaseActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_base"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.CreditCardDetails"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.PaymentActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.WalletActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.WalletAmountAddActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.UserServicesListActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.AddandEditUserServicesActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.Service_Individual_Details"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.BookAppointmet_Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.Service_UserProfileActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ProfileActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.Availability_Post_Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.FollowList_Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.BookingsListingActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.BookingIndividualDetails"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SaloonExpertsListActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.Reschedule_Booking_Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.User_Customer_Listing"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.User_Services_Availability_Listing"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.Customers_Add_Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.UsersListActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.Review_ListingActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.Availability_Subscription_ListingActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.User_Subscription_ListingActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.Portfolio_Service_Provider_ListingActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.Portfolio_Add_Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.Refer_Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.Report_Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.Post_Discounts_Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.Discount_Listing_Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />



    <!-- ===================== Jockey Activities ===================== -->

    <activity
        android:name=".jockey.activity.UserActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".jockey.activity.CarDetailsPost"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".jockey.activity.JockyDriverHomePage"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".jockey.activity.CarListviewProfilePage"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".jockey.activity.UserTripHistoryActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".jockey.activity.DriverSidePickUpList"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".jockey.activity.JockySettingPage"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".jockey.activity.DriverConfirmRide"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".jockey.activity.DriverSideTrackingPage"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".jockey.activity.JockyProfileActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".jockey.activity.DriverTripHistoryActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".jockey.activity.InternetConnectionCheck"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".jockey.activity.StartRide"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".jockey.activity.UserSideTrackingPage"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity android:name=".jockey.activity.UserHome_Jockey" />
    <activity android:name=".jockey.activity.DriverList_SwipingCards" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ChatActivity45"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".jockey.activity.BrainTreeMainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>



    <activity
        android:name="com.braintreepayments.api.BraintreeBrowserSwitchActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="${applicationId}.braintree" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>





</application>
```

please tell me what i have to do?

Comment: post the gradle log

Comment: Your manifest has errors. Post it

Comment: @cricket_007 i have added my manifest file please check that

Answer (score 2):

here problem is my minSdkVersion is 15. And twilio chat minSdkVersion is 19.

So i got error. so I changed my minSdkVersion to 19 and now working fine.